# PHP ternary conditional. Yes or no and why?

Tags: php, syntax, ternary-operator

I've been told to not use ternary conditional operators (?:) unless necessary.

My question is, why?

I like to use the ternary operator when writing an if/else would only be one statement each. I think it looks easier to me and it's easier to write.

Again, only if it's really really short (1 line of if/else). I can understand why nested and multiple ternary are evil.

So what is the problem with this way of doing things? Is it all a matter of preference or are there performance costs?

Also, whenever I have more than 2 or 3 conditions for else or elseif, I usually use a switch statement. Is this good practice?

Comment: choose your syntax for human readability, not for concision nor for performance. Let compiler/interpreter handle performance at this level, and optimize yourself after profiling. So : use the syntax that will make your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem (and have never heard of a problem) with the tertiary operator. In fact, it makes code more concise and, unless the reader is a beginner, more clear in my opinion.

Again, `switch` is really just an abstraction and it's more about the clarity. I use switch when I only rely on one variable. If you're requiring extra checks inside each case that's bad, but it seems like you're already pretty conscious of these things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with it either. And as for performance, these type of things are usually just "syntax sugar". Basically it translates to the same code under the hood, so it's just for your convenience. Of course, if it ends up making your code less convenient to read/write, then there is no sane reason to use it.

Answer (score 0):

strange my senior tells me to use ternary operator whenver you are just testing for just a true or false condition and it is faster too . and i agree with it .

but in case of of multiple conditions i always prefer if else loops its easy .

and i have never used switch statement , since if else do the job for me .

```
   so ternary opertor are best for one line of if else and its easy and fast
```

only reason they are not preffred for multiplte if else is because its become complex and error prone for new users